# Python Ray: Any good resources other than the website about the Ray API for python?

Tags: python, ray

I would like to learn more about the Ray API but was hoping to find some easy to read information regarding this python module. The website is great but I find it abit of a challenge to follow.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know of any books but you should try reading their official page :

[RAY API](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-overview/index.html)

Comment: You are very welcome